"No operator '<<' matches these operands" error for JSON::Value, how to write it to cout?
My C++ program below is supposed to read a json file called english.json and display the "title" information.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <json/value.h>
#include <json/reader.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Json::Value language;
    ifstream language_file("english.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    language_file >> language;

    cout << language["title"] << endl;

    return 0;
}

But when I run the program, I get this error:

E0349 No operator "<<" matches these operands

The program cannot display the information.
I looked at the documentation, but it wasn't very clear, so I couldn't find the source of the problem.
I've also try to include the json.h file, but it causes other errors related to "unresolved external symbols".

See this answer in the dupe that solves the problem.

@user12002570 That answer doesn't address how to make cout << language["title"] << endl; work though.

@Alan What part of the dupe explains what OP has to do to make cout << language["title"] << endl; work?

@Alan The dupe Q is "is there a way I can get the object as an std::string?" - so my answer would be very strange to that question.

@Alan But... there is already an operator<< overload that you'll have available if you do as I explain in my answer.

WAT? OP ask exact same question 2 days ago and got answer which he approved: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78754068/1387438 Can you explain what was the problem with other question responses?

@MarekR That dupe wasn't in the list when I reopened the question. Yours looks more like a real dupe I think - although it's about operator>> but the remedy is the same.

The operator<< overload you are trying to use is declared in json/writer.h so you need include that too, or replace all your json/* includes with #include <json/json.h>, which will include all the rest of the jsoncpp header files.
Another option is to call the correct as* member function to get the actual value from the Json::Value, eg:
std::cout << language["title"].asString() << '\n';
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^

You also need to link with the jsoncpp library to not get "unresolved external symbols".

Woot! Looks like I even got the syntax right. Maybe I should have answered!

@user4581301 Yeah. It was a long time since I used jsoncpp so I had to check the doc. ;)

Try this :
cout << language["title"].asString() << endl;


No. Try not. Do. Or do not. There is no try. -Yoda. But seriously, a good answer will explain what went wrong and why asString is needed.
